# ERROR: relation "student_id_seq" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Tags: postgresql

I have the following SQL code:

```
-- Table: public.student

-- DROP TABLE public.student;

CREATE TABLE public.student
(

   id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('student_id_seq'::regclass),
   country character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   email character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   section character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   sex character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
) 
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.student
OWNER to postgres;
```

My query does not execute

> ERROR:  relation "student_id_seq" does not exist
>   SQL state: 42P01

Comment: You get that error because you didn't create the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

In your query `id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('student_id_seq'::regclass)` that mean you want your table get the next value store in Sequence `student_id_seq` for default value of column `id`.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.student (
id serial not null,
country character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
email character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
section character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
sex character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH ( OIDS = FALSE ) TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.student OWNER to postgres;
```

By assigning the SERIAL pseudo-type to the id column, PostgreSQL will perform the following:

- Creates a sequence object and set the next value generated by the
  sequence as the default value for the column.
- Assigns the owner of the sequence to the id column; as a result, the sequence object is deleted when the id column or table is dropped

You can get more information [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/)

Answer (score 1):

Provide schema name before the sequence. Example: schema_name. has been added
here

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('schema_name.student_id_seq'::regclass),
```

Answer (score 0):

You either create a sequence or create id column with serial type.